# About Upstream version choice

Tags: upstream

I have questions about how to choice or decide which Upstream version to use for a certain software in Ubuntu Derived series.
is there some guiding principle or refer documents.
i.e.,why choice gcc-9.3.0 in the Focal Fossa.
thanks.

Comment: A key "guiding principle" for anyone trying to make a derivative of Ubuntu is to limit the chosen work to a feasible number of hours for the number of developers involved. Choosing and packaging specific upstream versions means that you also want to  integrate and test that software with your system, provide ongoing support, and new-release packaging. Each of those tasks requires some developer-hours and volunteer-hours.